# qt5.2 alpha creates bottom action bar. How to remove it?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, qt5

I could build qt5.2 on mac for android. And was able run my first application. Of course there is problem with styles but i can live with it - qt css will help.
Main problem which i can't solve is bottom action bar. Qt adds there single button and pressing opens QMainWindow main menu in separate view. At first i don't like such menu handling, moreover i wouldn't create menu at all for android application. Instead i would create my own bottom bar with my own buttons and so on. And of course i can do it in qt window, but how to remove bottom precreated action bar? Or, not so good method for me, how to add there my own items from qt app? I would even change qt generated java bootstrap code if it works.

Comment: Post code so we can have an understanding of what needs to be done

Comment: There is no code. I just generated Qt GUI application and run it on android device. I can post here generated code but not sure it help understand issue. I would count for some qt developers which worked with android already.